# Debian system will not start network interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, memory, debian, motherboard

Got a HDD array used to store data. The system runs Debian with the 4.9.0-7 kernel. Everything worked fine. Motherboard is a Supermicro XSIL8-F (http://www.supermicro.com/xeon_3400/motherboard/x8sil.cfm) with an i3 core processor. Has KVR1333D3E9SK2/8G RAM (DDR3 1333MHz PC3 10600). All networking is done through the onboard NIC.

RAM usage has been pretty heavy on it, so I upgraded it with an additional 8GB (2x 4GB). Installed the same RAM that is already in there to bring to total up to 16GB. Double-checked the seating of the chips. All good.

Booted the machine, it detects the 16 GB RAM fine -- no problems there.

When I got to a login prompt, I attempted to log in with my regular username. Didn't work. Hmmm. Then tried a root login. Also didn't work. The networking service wasn't starting and we handle all of our accounts using a NIS master, which explains the login problems.

When I examine /var/log/syslog, I see

```
... Failed to start Raised network interfaces
```

I've accessed a root shell through Grub, but still cannot get the network service up and running.

Thinking this is an issue with the RAM, I removed the recently installed RAM and rebooted and still the network service does not start.

As far as I can tell everything else is working fine. What could cause this?

**UPDATE:**

No errors from `dmesg` regarding NIC drivers. e100 and e1000e modules are loaded according to `lsmod`.

Running `service networking start` or `ifup enp7s0` starts the networking and NIC, and I am able to ping other servers. So I take it the NIC is good and I didn't fry anything!

Running any instance of `systemctl` returns

`Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`

and any instance of `init` returns

`Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn`

I guess this is OK since I'm using a recovery shell and this shouldn't be a problem. Or is it?

I've changed the title of this question to reflect the fact that the memory is not the issue.

**UPDATE2:**
I missed this error

`ifup[4675]: iptables-restore: line 20 failed`

which is a command to source an iptables rules file. For some reason, this is killing the machine. It hadn't before. Possibly a corrupt file.

So, all is good, now.

Comment: "Thinking this is an issue with the RAM, I removed the recently installed RAM and rebooted and still the network service does not start." - If you removed the memory you just installed, and you still have the problem, then the memory is not at fault.  "What could cause this?" - [It isn't caused by your memory.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824376/failed-to-start-raise-network-interfaces-after-upgrading-to-16-04)

Comment: Thanks ramhound. My reasoning behind the memory conclusion is the problem began after I installed the memory. Before thos, everything worked great. I've seen the thread you have linked to but have not gotten any ideas from it.

Comment: The way to debug this is too look at `dmesg` after boot for any error messages of the network card driver(s). Also, check cabling, seat of cards etc.; you may have touched something while installing RAM.

Comment: Turns out the issue was a possibly corrupted `if-pre-up,d/iptables` script used to source some iptables rules. Thanks, everyone for your consideration!